# how to write the minimum hourly value in fortran?

Tags: fortran, forecasting

This script reads 5 day forecasts from a weather model, and averages a few variables monthly hourly.

Now, I need to get the minimum temperature value.
Example, each day I have 5 days of forecast.

I need an output like this:
January
minimum value of 0h, 1h, 2h, 3h, 4h, etc. It doesn't matter what day it is in January, just the monthly hourly minimum value.

```
program medias
implicit none

   INTEGER,PARAMETER :: NVARS=5 
   INTEGER :: IM, JM, YEAR2, MONTH2, DAY2, YEAR, MONTH, DAY, LASTYEAR, &
LASTMONTH, LASTDAY, H1, H2, H3, H7, H8, A, B, V, X, Y, TDEF=0
   REAL :: LAT, LON, RESX=0.0466611, RESY=0.0448676
   INTEGER, DIMENSION(12)                  :: CALENDAR
   CHARACTER(LEN=3), DIMENSION(12)         :: MONTHS = (/ 'Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec' /)
   CHARACTER(LEN=5), DIMENSION(NVARS)      :: VARNAMES = (/ 'PRECI','T2MJU','TD2MJ','U10MJ','V10MJ' /)
        REAL, DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE       :: SURVAR
        REAL, DIMENSION(:,:,:,:), ALLOCATABLE   :: HOURLY2D, HOURLY2DF, MONTHLY2D, MONTHLY2DF          
        
        CHARACTER             :: DATE*8, DIROUT*200, DIRRUN*200, FILENAME*200, DYEAR*4, DMONTH*2, DDAY*2, DHOUR*2


! DADOS DE ENTRADA
DIRRUN = '/media/milena/Backup/'
!DIRRUN = '/home/oper/prevtempo/dataout/GrADS_BRAMS-6.5.2/'
DIROUT = '/media/milena/Backup/'
IM = 259
JM = 269
   
CALENDAR = (/ 31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31 /)
H8 = 24
ALLOCATE(SURVAR(IM,JM))
ALLOCATE(HOURLY2DF(IM,JM,H8,5))
ALLOCATE(MONTHLY2DF(IM,JM,12,5))


! Iniciando o armazenamento de dados 

   TDEF = 0

    YEAR = 2022
    MONTH = 10 
    LASTMONTH = 10
    LASTYEAR = 2022

    H7 = 0
    YEAR2 = YEAR
    MONTH2 = MONTH
    

2  H7 = H7+1
   
   H2 = 0
    
    DO WHILE (H2 .LE. 23)

    YEAR = YEAR2
    MONTH = MONTH2
   PRINT*, MONTH
   PRINT*, YEAR

    H1 = ((LASTYEAR-YEAR)+1)*31*5
    ALLOCATE(HOURLY2D(IM,JM,H1,5))
 

    H1 = 0

    WRITE (DHOUR,'(BZ,I2.2)') H2
    TDEF = TDEF+1

    DO WHILE (YEAR .LE. LASTYEAR)

    
    IF (MOD(YEAR,4) .EQ. 0) CALENDAR(2) = 29    

    LASTDAY = CALENDAR(MONTH)
    
!    IF (MONTH .EQ. LASTMONTH) LASTDAY = 12
 
    DAY = 1
    
    DO WHILE (DAY .LE. LASTDAY)
    DAY2 = DAY

   A = 8
        
    WRITE (DATE,'(BZ,I4.4,3I2.2)') YEAR,MONTH,DAY
    WRITE (DYEAR,'(BZ,I4.4)') YEAR
    WRITE (DMONTH,'(BZ,I2.2)') MONTH
        
    IF (H2 .EQ. 0) THEN
    DAY2 = DAY2+1
              IF ( DAY2 .GT. LASTDAY ) THEN
              GO TO 22
              END IF
    END IF
    
    WRITE (DDAY,'(BZ,I2.2)') DAY2


8  FILENAME = TRIM(DIRRUN)//DATE//'00/Go05km-A-'//DYEAR//'-'//DMONTH//'-'//DDAY//'-'//DHOUR//'0000-g1.gra'
   OPEN(8,FILE=TRIM(FILENAME),ACCESS="direct",ACTION="read",STATUS="old",RECL=IM*JM*4)
   H1 = H1+1
   GO TO 21

9  FILENAME = TRIM(DIRRUN)//DATE//'00/Go05km-A-'//DYEAR//'-'//DMONTH//'-'//DDAY//'-'//DHOUR//'0000-g1.gra'
   OPEN(9,FILE=TRIM(FILENAME),ACCESS="direct",ACTION="read",STATUS="old",RECL=IM*JM*4)
   H1 = H1+1
   GO TO 21

10  FILENAME = TRIM(DIRRUN)//DATE//'00/Go05km-A-'//DYEAR//'-'//DMONTH//'-'//DDAY//'-'//DHOUR//'0000-g1.gra'
   OPEN(10,FILE=TRIM(FILENAME),ACCESS="direct",ACTION="read",STATUS="old",RECL=IM*JM*4)
   H1 = H1+1
   GO TO 21

11  FILENAME = TRIM(DIRRUN)//DATE//'00/Go05km-A-'//DYEAR//'-'//DMONTH//'-'//DDAY//'-'//DHOUR//'0000-g1.gra'
   OPEN(11,FILE=TRIM(FILENAME),ACCESS="direct",ACTION="read",STATUS="old",RECL=IM*JM*4)
   H1 = H1+1
   GO TO 21

12  FILENAME = TRIM(DIRRUN)//DATE//'00/Go05km-A-'//DYEAR//'-'//DMONTH//'-'//DDAY//'-'//DHOUR//'0000-g1.gra'
   OPEN(12,FILE=TRIM(FILENAME),ACCESS="direct",ACTION="read",STATUS="old",RECL=IM*JM*4)
   H1 = H1+1
   GO TO 21

13    GO TO 22 

21        B = 0

          DO V =1,175
                READ (A,REC=V) SURVAR(:,:)
! Leitura Precipitacao
                IF ( V .EQ. 162 ) THEN
                B = B+1
                HOURLY2D(:,:,H1,B) = SURVAR(:,:)
    
                END IF
! Leitura Tp2m
                IF ( V .EQ. 166 ) THEN
                B = B+1
                HOURLY2D(:,:,H1,B) = SURVAR(:,:)
    
                END IF
! Leitura Td2m
                IF ( V .EQ. 167 ) THEN
                B = B+1
                HOURLY2D(:,:,H1,B) = SURVAR(:,:)
    
                END IF

! Leitura U10m
                IF ( V .EQ. 168 ) THEN
                B = B+1
                HOURLY2D(:,:,H1,B) = SURVAR(:,:)
    
                END IF
! Leitura V10m
                IF ( V .EQ. 169 ) THEN
                B = B+1
                HOURLY2D(:,:,H1,B) = SURVAR(:,:)
    
                END IF
          END DO
 
          CLOSE(A)


              A = A+1

              DAY2 = DAY2+1
              WRITE (DDAY,'(BZ,I2.2)') DAY2

              IF ( DAY2 .GT. LASTDAY ) THEN
              GO TO 22
              END IF

              GO TO (9,10,11,12,13),A-8
                                            
              
22  DAY = DAY+1
    END DO

    YEAR = YEAR+1

    IF (MONTH .GT. LASTMONTH) THEN
    GO TO 23
    END IF

    END DO


23  DO B=1,5
    DO Y=1,JM
    DO X=1,IM
      HOURLY2DF(X,Y,H2,B) = SUM(HOURLY2D(X,Y,1:H1,B))/H1
    END DO
    END DO
    END DO

  PRINT*,H2
  PRINT*, HOURLY2DF(130,107,H2,1)
  PRINT*, HOURLY2DF(130,107,H2,2)
  PRINT*, HOURLY2DF(130,107,H2,3)
  PRINT*, HOURLY2DF(130,107,H2,4)
  PRINT*, HOURLY2DF(130,107,H2,5)  

  DEALLOCATE(HOURLY2D)
  H2 = H2+1
  END DO

40  FILENAME = TRIM(DIROUT)//'MEDIA_HORARIA_'//DMONTH//'.bin'
PRINT*, FILENAME
OPEN(40,FILE=TRIM(FILENAME),ACCESS="direct",ACTION="write",STATUS="new",RECL=IM*JM*4)                                                       

    H3=1
    H2=H2-1
    DO H2=0,H2
    DO B=1,5
    WRITE(40,rec=H3) HOURLY2DF(:,:,H2,B)
    H3=H3+1
    END DO
    END DO
    CLOSE(40)

    DO B=1,5
    DO Y=1,JM
    DO X=1,IM
      MONTHLY2DF(X,Y,H7,B) = SUM(HOURLY2DF(X,Y,0:H2,B))/(H2+1)
    END DO
    END DO
    END DO

    PRINT*,'MEDIA MENSAL DO MES ',DMONTH
    PRINT*, MONTHLY2DF(153,117,H7,1)
    PRINT*, MONTHLY2DF(153,117,H7,2)
    PRINT*, MONTHLY2DF(153,117,H7,3)
    PRINT*, MONTHLY2DF(153,117,H7,4)
    PRINT*, MONTHLY2DF(153,117,H7,5)

    MONTH2 = MONTH2+1 
    IF (MONTH2 .GT. 12) THEN
    MONTH2 = 1
    YEAR2 = YEAR2+1
    END IF

    IF (MONTH2 .LE. LASTMONTH) THEN
    IF (H7 .LE. 12) THEN
     GO TO 2
    END IF
    END IF


50  FILENAME = TRIM(DIROUT)//'MEDIA_MENSAL_01.bin'
    OPEN(50,FILE=TRIM(FILENAME),ACCESS="direct",ACTION="write",STATUS="new",RECL=IM*JM*4)                                                       

    H3=1
    DO H7=1,H7
    DO B=1,5
    WRITE(50,rec=H3) MONTHLY2DF(:,:,H7,B)
    H3=H3+1
    END DO
    END DO
    
    CLOSE(50)

END PROGRAM medias
```

Comment: removing all the unrelated tags

Comment: Ye gods, why all the `goto`s? And a computed goto of all things! I suggest you sort out the structure so it's easier to understand, then you'll be more likely to get an answer - I haven't found a good use for goto in Fortran probably for over 2 decades. Computed goto probably shouldn't have been used in over 30 years.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou, as the sample code isn't (even close to being) Fortran 77, [tag:fortran77] doesn't seem appropriate to me.

Comment: That's a lot of code (see [mre] for general guidance about that) which we can't run (not having your input data), so it would be helpful if you can explain exactly what you are struggling with.

Comment: The answer is probably ... use the intrinsic function `minval` across one of the dimensions of one of the multi-dimensional arrays.  OP will probably figure that out before I can understand the code in sufficient detail for a proper answer.